# How to remove menu bar from the window that opens with an external URL of an Electron application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, menubar, electron-react

I have the below code to remove menu bar from the window that opens with an external URL of an Electron application.

```
windowObject.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(() => ({
  action: 'allow',
  overrideBrowserWindowOptions: {
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
  },
}));
```

But the menu pops up when "Alt" key is pressed which is a short-key conflict with my application. So, is there any way to prevent this behavior ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this, it should fix it depending on what version of eletron your using

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = require('electron')
Menu.setApplicationMenu(false)
```

if the previous code does not work try doing this

```js
    let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        autoHideMenuBar: true
    })
```

Comment: Menu.setApplicationMenu(false) just removes the menu bar from the main window and all of the child windows as well. Thanks :)